# Prevent onComplete exit in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I would like to make multiple calls of `test` function, but after first time, that `jasmine.onComplete` is called, the programs exits. I already know, that I can't do multiple test in parallel, but I thought, that I may be able to queue them, but if the jasmine exit the node I am done. Therefor:

Is there a way to prevent jasmine to exit node?

```
const toCall = {}
jasmine.onComplete(function(passed) {
    toCall[varReporter.last.name](passed, varReporter.last.result)
    toCall[varReporter.last.name] = null
});

function test(folder, file, callback){
    toCall[file] = callback
    jasmine.execute(['JS/' + folder + '/tests/' + file + '.js'])
}

//  User saves a file, a test get triggered.
test('prototype', 'Array', function(passed, result){
    console.log(util.inspect(result, { colors: true, depth: null }))
})

//  User saves an other file and an other test should get triggered, but can't.
```

My test will not be called in groups, but one after an other, based on users interactions with files. I need to run test after each save, so that I can determine whenever I should process them or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override jasmine exit option:

```
jasmine.exit = () => {};
```

But that causes various glitches.
I'd rather run whole script in another process:

**run-test.js**

```
const path = require('path'),
    Jasmine = require('jasmine/lib/jasmine.js');

const jasmine = new Jasmine({ projectBaseDir: path.resolve() });
jasmine.execute(process.argv.slice(2));
```

**watch-tests.js**

```
const fork = require('child_process').fork;

function test(folder, file) {
    fork('run-test.js', ['JS/' + folder + '/tests/' + file + '.js']);
}

//  User saves a file, a test get triggered.
test('prototype', 'Array')
//  User saves an other file and an other test should get triggered, but can't.
```

Comment: This is actually what I ended up with... Mainly for the reason, that I can then run multiple test (even in parallel, not that it would be necesery, but still it is nice to have)

Comment: Just for clarification, you should add close listener to the fork, just so people can see how to do it properly